# Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly<Attributes & { children?: ComponentChildren; ref?: Ref<any>; }>'

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Написал компонент, в теле рендера которого пытаюсь вызвать другой компонент:

```
render() {
    return(
        <div className="sort-element">
            <this.heading label="Багаж" reset="baggage" />
                <div className="sorter-content">
                    <Toggle id="baggage-toggle" />
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Компонент **Toggle** объявлен в другом файле `toggle.tsx` и в нём нет ошибок:

```
export default function Toggle(props : { id : string }) {
    return (
        <div class="toggle-holder">
            <input id={props.id} type="checkbox" />
            <label for={props.id}></label>
        </div>
    )
}
```

А вот в основном файле вызов компонента  подчёркивается и выводятся ошибки:

> Type '{ id: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Readonly; }>'.
>
> Property 'id' does not exist on type 'Readonly; }>'.ts(2322)

Как это исправить?

Answer (score 0):

У меня был объявлен класс:

```
export default class Sorter extends Component<{}, {}>
```

А должен был быть объявлен с **any**:

```
export default class Sorter extends Component<any, any>
```